# How to search string in array of macthing regex

Tags: php

I have an array containing regular expressions.
The point is that I want to run a function if any input string matches with any of these expressions whiteout any loops.
 
example of expressions array:

```php
$array = [
       '^expression_(.*)',
       '^expression2_(.*)',
       'expression3',
];
```

Comment: Without any loops doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this condition:

```php
if(preg_match('/'.implode('|',$array).'/', $string)){

    //todo

}
```

Comment: You may have to enclose them in brackets as well `()`. I am also unsure about the time complexity overhead that this might introduce over matching one by one.